# What is difference between translate use and setDefault?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Does anybody knows what is mayor difference between angular translate

```
transate.use();
```

and method

```
translate.setDefault();
```

I have problem when I have added async pipe in template I can not get translation, until I have added .use(). Maybe it has something with the streams?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#3-init-the-translateservice-for-your-application) :

```
// this language will be used as a fallback when a translation isn't found in the current language
translate.setDefaultLang('en');

 // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
translate.use('en');
```

Answer (score 0):

**FALLBACK**:The method translate.setDefaultLang('en') allows you to specify a fallback set of translations to use in case there are missing translations for the current language.

**Current**:translate.use('en') tells the service which is the current language to use for translations.

I can't see your code but for now my and will be you need to specify both on start

Comment: If you think there's information missing, it's best to ask the author in a comment **before** answering the question.